# Working with bytes in clipboard

Tags: javascript, byte, arrays, clipboard

Consider the following situation:

There's a web application (subject of question), and a third-party desktop application.

Desktop application allows copying and pasting pieces of content from/to it.

Clipboard data consists of a text (providing a fallback snippet of content) and the actual data in XML format (containing quite more information than the text snippet).

And all would be fine, but there's a catch: **XML data is stored a byte array instead of string**.

While the exact reasons of storing XML data as a byte array will probably remain a mystery, working with that from a web application remains a subject of curiosity.

First, to clipboard contents. While the actual format is slightly more complicated than this, working with data from another desktop application can be summed up with this: [(a C# gist)](https://gist.github.com/YellowAfterlife/5ad959c31986019e293e)

Then, to my attempts. So far I have tried working with this from JavaScript [(jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/57J5c/3/):

```
var field = document.getElementById("field");
var log = document.getElementById("log");
//
field.oncopy = function(e) {
    var cd = e.clipboardData;
    if (cd == null) {
        log.value = "ClipboardData is not supported.";
        return;
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    var value = field.value;
    cd.setData("Text", "Text: " + value);
    cd.setData("Xml", "<value>" + value + "</value>");
}
//
field.onpaste = function(e) {
    var cd = e.clipboardData;
    if (cd == null) {
        log.value = "ClipboardData is not supported.";
        return;
    }
    log.value 
    = "Text: `" + cd.getData("Text") + "`\n"
    + "Xml: `" + cd.getData("Xml") + "`\n";
}
```

and Haxe+Flash [(snippet)](http://try.haxe.org/#83453):

```
import flash.Lib;
import flash.desktop.Clipboard;
import flash.desktop.ClipboardFormats;
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var stage = Lib.current.stage;
        stage.addEventListener("click", function(_) {
            var clip = Clipboard.generalClipboard;
            clip.clear();
            clip.setData(ClipboardFormats.TEXT_FORMAT, "(text)");
            clip.setData(cast "Xml", "(xml)");
            trace("Copied!");
        });
    }
}
```

So far... to no avail. JS can't read the XML data written by desktop application, and desktop application can't read the "XML" field written by either JS or Flash.

I'm pretty sure that I'm doing something wrong, but I can't quite spot the problem.

Any help would be appreciated.